# Why is this simplification and factorization possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a fundamental doubt about simplification and factorization.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\,-3\,\}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is defined as follows:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+2x-3}{x+3}$$

by the distributive property:
$$f(x)=\frac{(x+3)(x-1)}{x+3}$$

by division:
$$f(x)=x-1$$

Why is this possible? the domain of $f$ of the first line is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\,-3\,\}$, but the $f$ in the third line accepts $-3$. Are different functions? or it's the same and always is implicit that $x \neq 3$?.

Sorry if this question is trivial or dumb, and excuse my English too, please.

Comment: For $x\ne -3$ , both functions are identical , but not for $x=-3$ since the first is not defined there. If we only consider the domain of the original function, there is no difference at all.

Comment: Any time someone writes a function as just an expression, the question "What is its domain?" is kind of up in the air, and they are depending on the reader to make the most reasonable guess. But, having been specifically told the domain of $f$ early on, it doesn't magically change when show it is equally to some other everywhere-define function.

Comment: As noted in previous comments, since the stated domain omits $x=-3$, there is no controversy here. That said, it's worth noting that, *because* of this algebraic simplification, the original function has what's often called a "removable discontinuity"; ie, the graph has a *hole*, instead of, say, a *jump* or an *asymptote*. In some contexts, we implicitly/hand-wavingly allow such a function to fill itself in at the trouble spot, *removing the removable discontinuity*, and naturally extending to a broader domain. (This kind of thing happens a lot with trig simplifications.)

Comment: @Blue - I've seen actual arguments as to whether or not that should be considered to take place automatically when dealing with complex analytic functions with a removable discontinuity.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Well, I *did* hedge by writing *"in some contexts"*. ;)

Comment: Thank you all. I'm going to continue investigating about "removable discontinuity". thank you.

Comment: @Blue - Oh, I hope it didn't sound like I was disagreeing with you. I just wanted to let the OP know that they might stumble onto people passionately advocating for one convention or the other.